# maven read pom.xml containing multiple modules and write file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

We have "master" pom.xml file and has multiple modules, using `maven-antrun-plugin` or other plugin, how do we be able to achieve by means of writing a file to all module folders in this master pom.xml? Want to store a file containing "${project.version}". For instance, we run `mvn clean verify`, we want to retrieve the version from this master pom.xml and store as file to all multiple modules.

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mp</groupId>
<artifactId>parentApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>parentApp</name>
<description>This is just to test pom inheritance</description>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<modules>
        <module>../example1</module>
        <module>../example2</module>
        <module>../example3</module>
        <module>../example4</module>
        <module>../example5</module>
..
..
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What problem do you want to solve with this?

Comment: Hello @JFabianMeier :we are using "maven CI friendly" plugin or "flatten-maven-plugin" to get the version passed down to multiple modules.Which is we have jenkins CI to generate version on master pom and pass down to multiple modules by storing the version in a file ".mvn/maven.config"

Comment: @HareKrshn I would suggest you to describe more thoroughly what is your ultimate goal, the "we need to get some files in project directory" does look like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1109023), because since you are using jenkins you may write any file using built-in groovy

Comment: Please make a full working example on github or alike... furthermore flatten-maven-plugin and why do you need a supplemental file `"${project.version}"`may be you could go via resource filtering???

Answer (score -2):

Never mind - we can add `exec-maven-plugin`  to run the bash script to list all multiple modules, for loop - copy the folder to all modules.